# How to access or get information about my SoftLayer ordered Object Storage?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

So I created an order for Object Storage in SoftLayer.
For other storage, I can use SoftLayer_Account::getIscsiNetworkStorage() as an example to get Block Storge that I've ordered.
For an Object Storage, what can I use to get a list of access what I just ordered?

It seems like ordering an Object Storage creates some OpenStack Object Storage account.  I tried methods like getOpenStackAccountLinks and getOpenStackObjectStorage on SoftLayer_Account but they return empty list.

So how do I get information on the Object Storage object that I ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try to use

> SoftLayer_Account::getHubNetworkStorage

References:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getHubNetworkStorage

I hope this information can help you,

Regards

Comment: Thanks. I am guessing that would work. I found a more generic one that seems to work.  getNetworkStorage().  I guess ObjectStorage is a network storage, so it's included there as well as getHubNetworkStorage().